# Rounding up double numbers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, double, int, rounding

I need C code for rounding up a double value to the next greatest integer value.

For example, if I have:

`1.0 (double)` it must be `1 (int)`
`1.01 (double)` it must be `2 (int)`
`5.67 (double)` it must be `6 (int)`
`76.43 (double)` it must be `77 (int)`

Is there a solution?

Comment: [So many duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+round+up+double)...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`ceil()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ceil) function from `<math.h>`:

```
#include <math.h>

double x = 1.01;     // x = 1.01
double y = ceil(x);  // y = 2.0
int i = (int)y;      // i = 2
```

or more concisely, if you just want the int result:

```
int i = (int)ceil(x);
```

Comment: You might want to check the range of the result before converting to `int`, since otherwise the conversion invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.: true - for simplicity I'm assuming that the result is known to lie within the range of an `int` but in the more general case we need to perform range checking prior to conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say your float number is `nr`.
No build-in functions:

```
float nr;
int temp;
if (nr % 10 > 0) {
    temp = nr++;
} else {
    temp = nr;
}
nr = temp;
```

Comment: Aside from the unnecessary assignments (`nr++`?), implicit casting, and verbosity, there is an error in the code: `nr % 10` should probably be `nr % 1`.